# Pubnub functions not working on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, pubnub, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use [history method](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/storage-and-history)  provided by Pubnub to get the chat history of a channel and running my node.js code on AWS Lambda. However, my function is not getting called. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, but here's the code snippet-

```js
var publishKey = "pub-c-cfe10ea4-redacted";
var subscribeKey = "sub-c-fedec8ba-redacted";
var channelId = "ChatRoomDemo";
var uuid;
var pubnub = {};

function readMessages(intent,session,callback){
    pubnub = require("pubnub")({
               publish_key   : publishKey,
               subscribe_key: subscribeKey
             });

    pubnub.history({
        channel : 'ChatRoomDemo',
        callback : function(m){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
        },
        count : 100, 
        reverse : false 
    });
}
```

I expect the message history in JSON format to be displayed on the console.

Comment: if those are your real pub/sub keys, you should not provide them to the public. recommend disabling those keys and creating new ones.

Comment: You may need to enable ACL rules for your Lambda Container.  Specified in  AWS security console.  Specifically external HTTP calls to `*.pubnub.com`

Comment: One of our architects suspects that because the `history` response is asynchronous that your Lambda is exiting before the results are returned to your callback. We will follow up with confirmation on this and a best practice.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and finally got it working.  What you will need to do is allow the CIDR address for pubnub.com.  This was a foreign idea to me until I figured it out!  Here's how to do that to publish to a channel:

1. Copy the CIDR address for pubnub.com which is 54.246.196.128/26 ([Source](https://myip.ms/view/ip_ranges/1337198/54.246.196.128_54.246.196.191)) **[WARNING: do not this - see comment below]**
2. Log into https://console.aws.amazon.com
3. Under "Services" go to "VPC"
4. On the left, under "Security," click "Network ACLs"
5. Click "Create Network ACL" give it a name tag like "pubnub.com"
6. Select the VPC for your Lambda skill (if you're not sure, click around your Lambda function, you'll see it.  You probably only have one listed like me)
7. Click "Yes, Create"
8. Under the "Outbound Rules" tab, click "Edit"
9. For "Rule #" I just used "1"
10. For "Type" I used "HTTP (80)"
11. For "Destination" I pasted in the CIDR from step 1
12. "Save"[image]

Note, if you're **subscribing** to a channel, you'll also need to add an "Inbound Rule" too.

Comment: NOTE: hardcoding a specific IP Address to connect to PubNub is not condoned by PubNub. Why? Because PubNub is a distribute network and your requests are routed to the server node through DNS lookup. IP addresses can and will change so hardcoding the IP Address will eventually fail. And if failover is necessary due to a faulty node, then failover will... fail. So do not do this, please.

Comment: If you have a real project that you need a solution to and would like discuss best practices, please contact [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support) for further assistance.

Comment: @CraigConover, would you care to suggest what an appropriate value for the CIDR address is then?

Comment: Not at this time. Just don't hard code PubNub IP addresses. It possibly would be appropriate provide the full list of public PubNub IP addresses or perhaps somehow be able to map it to pubsub.pubnub.com so that the DNS is exercised. We will provide an official answer though.

Comment: Thank you, I look forward to it because my answer is the only way I've been able to get my Amazon Echo to talk to PubNub successfully.  Seeing a tutorial for this on your website would be awesome!